# ag-grid export to excel with partial style on cell

Tags: javascript, angular, export-to-excel, ag-grid

[image: In screenshot]

I am facing problem in exporting data to excel from ag-grid, when my cell contains item with multiple color. For example in the attached screenshot, I am able to export entire "My View Name 23" in red or in black but not having both black and red colors.

[image]

Using ag-grid cellRendeter to modify the cell value.

Is it a known limitation in ag-grid? Or is there a way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello ak13, can you explain your photo ? It is Excel image of what you want on Excel ?  Can you give a screenshot of ag-grid with both colors ? Please, can you put a screenshot and not a photo ?

Comment: Hello schlebe,  Yes it is an excel image, attached the screenshot of ag-grid with both colors. I am using cellRendeter to add the CSS color. Thanks

Comment: Please, can you change photo by printscreen ?

Comment: I think that the best thing (for you) is to post your question on https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues ! When you have an answer on Github, you come back here to give what you have obtained.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? Could you post some code of how you're displaying the text in the cell in different colors to start with?